# Pygame Fonts Acting Up

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I'm making a simple game where a spaceship flies across the screen shooting aliens. Anyway I decided it would be nice to have a countdown before the game started and after that a way to display the score. The obvious choice, since I'm using pygame, was the pygame.font method. So I drafted up the code below through some internet searches and it turns out to only be working some of the time. When it does work I can see proof of all colours, font size, font type, placement, content etc. working. However a lot of the time at what seems as random occasions it returns the error message "Text has zero width" higliting the second line of code below. Again this is completely spontaneous without me changing any parameters. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
theFont= pygame.font.SysFont("C:\\ProgrammeringOne\\motion_control\\MotionControl-Bold", 15)

label = theFont.render("Some text!", 1, (255,255,0))

screen.blit(label, (40, 30))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to write whole path if you using `SysFont`. Only font name is enough if you put your font to main font folder in C.

Second, in here; `label = theFont.render("Some text!", 1, (255,255,0))` the `1` must be `True`. Replace `1` with `True`.

`label = theFont.render("Some text!", True, (255,255,0))`

About `sometimes it's working` , I'm not sure  but, you know actually `True` equal to `1`;

```
>>> True+True
2
>>>
```

So *maybe* that's why when you use `1` it's working.

Comment: That seems to have solved it, thanks. You don't happen to have an answer as to why it still worked sometimes though?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, weird, anyway thanks for your help, much obliged.